# Selenium WebDriver testing login verification/authentication

Tags: c#, selenium, ide, geckodriver, katalon-studio

I am using Katalon to build the base Selenium script of which will allow me to have an automated login for gmail. I do however need to add password and username verification in between my test method code. I just need help understanding and if possible, a base template, for how I should structure my verification code. As my title says, I just need help understanding how to code login verification. Thanks ahead of time. Here is my [Test Method]. I am removing my username and password for security reasons, however my username is in the structure of aaaa.heta97@gmail.com and my password follows this structure asd2098KAM.

```
[TestMethod]
    public void TheUntitledTestCaseTest()
    {
        driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://www.google.com/");
        driver.FindElement(By.LinkText("Gmail")).Click();
        driver.FindElement(By.LinkText("Sign In")).Click();
        driver.FindElement(By.Id("identifierId")).Clear();
        driver.FindElement(By.Id("identifierId")).SendKeys("aaaa.ksat97");
        driver.FindElement(By.Id("identifierId")).SendKeys(Keys.Enter);
        driver.FindElement(By.Name("password")).Clear();
        driver.FindElement(By.Name("password")).SendKeys("aln9178JKM");
        driver.FindElement(By.Name("password")).SendKeys(Keys.Enter);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You can assert if your username displays. A displayed username would indicate a successful login.
2. You can also see if a token/cookie is added to your session on login.
3. Or see what response gmail sends back on failure/successful login post. Depending on the response you can assert if it's a successful login or not.